# Contest statistical likelihood

Tags: probability

Apologies in advance for asking what is probably a very basic question, but I have zero knowledge of statistics.

I made 8 discrete entries to a contest.
The contest had 1,649 discrete entries.
The contest selected 10 entries.
2 of those entries were mine.

What is the statistical probability of this occurring?

Comment: Well, how were the 10 entries selected? At random? Or were they selected based on some objective criteria?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your question might be about the idea of hypothesis testing. You did good, certainly above average, but could this result just as well likely arrise when you all the results are random? The answer by Tim is the simplest approach and assumes that the random process is like drawing entries in an [urn problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urn_problem) where all draws are independent. But... are those assumptions correct? If the drawing process is random but not independent, then you might get a different answer.

Comment: To what does "this" refer?? Entering a contest?  Having 1649 entries?  Winning at least once?  Winning at least twice?  Winning at least once in at least one of the contests you ever enter in your life?  Having anyone win at least twice in this contest?  *Etc., etc.*

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give us many details, so let me assume that the contest can be understood as sampling randomly without replacement of $n=10$ winning entries from the urn consisting of $N=1,649$ entries in total. Among all the entries in the lottery $K=8$ are yours and your question is: what is the probability that among the $n$ selected items $k=2$ will be yours?

Stated like this, the problem can be described by [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) with the probability mass function

$$
\Pr(X = k) = \frac{{K \choose k}{N-k \choose n-k}}{N \choose n} 
$$

and the probability (calculated using statistical software R) is

```r
> dhyper(2, 8, 1649-8, 10)
[1] 0.0009005658
```

Comment: This *post hoc* probability doesn't appear to relevant to any statistical aspect of the situation and therefore might be misinterpreted by most readers.  See https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3207/919.

Comment: @whuber the question can be thought as a simple probability problem, I see no reason why not treating it like this.

Comment: @Tim underlying the question is a not only a simple probability computation, and implicitly this seems to be also a tricky statistical problem of hypothesis testing (with a selection effect and multiple comparisons). If somebody wins the lottery and they compute a very small probability for winning the lottery, should they reject the nul-hypothesis that they have no advantage in winning a lottery?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I don’t see OP asking any of those questions, but rather the simple one: “given the scenario, what is the probability” and it’s a valid question.

Comment: I don't see any definite question here, because no event has been clearly defined or described.